# Mixed content error - When served over HTTPS, swagger-ui should prefer HTTPS API protocol

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-3.0

When going to swagger ui link I see errors in console>

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://***url***/api/documentation/ui' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://***url***/swagger-ui-assets/favicon-16x16.png?v=47568366ac424fb77af3e26dce55c7cd'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

And so on for all the asssets

I have modified API docs json  file from witch we are generating the doc.
This part and changed http to https

```
"components": {
        "securitySchemes": {
            "bearer": {
                "type": "http",
                "description": "Passport security.",
                "scheme": "bearer",
                "bearerFormat": "JWT"
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect not to receive this error an see swagger UI

Comment: The section you've posted describes the security of the API you're documenting, which while it almost certainly should be using HTTPS, has nothing to do with how the documentation is hosted. Most likely, you've misconfigured something when you set up the Swagger-UI hosting, so your Apache/NGinx/IIS/etc configuration might be more relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have not configured it myself but from what I know it is running on a google kubrenetes cluster and should be using nginx. I will try to find some relavant configuration to add to question.